# PostgreSQL row sort with NULL values and empty string at last

Tags: postgresql

I have used the following SQL, and it's working fine, but I need to sort empty strings also.  Please give me guidance on this.

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM users
ORDER BY first_name DESC NULLS LAST
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 46):

Use some [conditional functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15562), e.g.

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(first_name, '') DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY IF( first_name = '' OR first_name IS NULL,1,0), first_name;